# Should data be standardized on the backend or the client (front-end, mobile app)?

Tags: architecture

I have a question: **Should data be standardized on the backend or the client (front-end, mobile app)?**

I take an example:

My return value is a json string:

```
{
    "product_name":"Dress X - L",
    ...
}
```

On the website we will display the value "Dress X - L".

But on mobile we will only display the value "X-L", so I want the client to do the extra task of cutting the returned product_name value with the "Dress" value stored in localstorage. The reason I don't want to process it on the backend is: to get the value "X-L", I have to handle some additional steps such as saving more fields in the table, making small edits and other processing.

However, client processors believe that all data needs to be processed on the backend, to be flexible in changing logic.

Our team could not agree on whether to process data on the backend or client side.
The above is just a small example of mine. I would like to ask in general terms, should we standardize data on the backend or the client (front-end, mobile app)?

Thanks for all the comments on this issue!

Comment: I would do it at the back-end, but then I woudn't be returning JSON, and I would be using JSF or similar to do the presentation layer, so almost everything is at the backend. Not too difficult to provide slightly different presentations for mobile. You could even accomplish it with a bit of CSS ...

Comment: Thanks for comment.

Yes, it's quite easy to edit mobile or client presentations. Basically, I usually divide data normalization depending on the effort required. But perhaps my thoughts are not correct.
What are your thoughts on whether data should be standardized on the backend or the client? Are there any standards? Or are there any pros and cons about it?

Comment: I’ve given you my thoughts. You’re just asking me to repeat myself.

Comment: Thanks @user207421.
This is a big thinking in software, but i dont know why there are anyone dislike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you have a backend API and different clients, which could be mobiles, websites and more (in the future). If this is the case, then you should decouple your backend from clients. So dont design your API thinking of the clients. Do it as if you knew nothing about the clients. This way you can create an extensible, maintainable etc service.

More specific, in your case, if you knew nothing about clients, then you should just return the json you mention and let clients handle their cases:

```
{
    "product_name":"Dress X - L",
    ...
}
```

But, if we knew nothing about clients and still wanted to be proactive, then we could think that the info `"product_name":"Dress X - L"` doesnt accurate. The single responsibility principle says that variable `product_name` should give back just the name. but value `Dress X - L` gives two other things, the type (?) and sizes. So i would say you need to either have 2 more properties in there, the product type (or leave it as product name. still makes sense). and the size in a different one. Then one client can display product_name + product_size (if not null? if you have products without sizes or might in the future) and the other one can just display product_size